# How big should one WebSocket request be?

Tags: javascript

There is probably a size, at which a request gets splitted.
Since I have to work with strings in the request, a answer with a char-count would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol itself (see [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-27)) supports payload lengths of up to 2^64 octets.

Individual requests do get split into "frames", but the protocol implementation will automatically join those back together and present the whole request as a single request to the WebSocket API.

Comment: Would it be a better strategy to minimize the frame count with smaller but more requests or to use bigger requests which get fragmented into more frames?

Comment: @da_b0uncer you should just send whatever data you need and not worry about the framing.

Comment: I know, but which of these strategies would be better if I have to worry about the ping?

Comment: @da_b0uncer generally (not talking about WebSockets here), fewer larger packets allow for higher throughput than lots of small packets.

Comment: So if I would "gather" my requests in a buffer an regulary send them all few milliseconds it would get me a better throughput, than sending every "requests" on demand? ... this probably depends on the amount of requests I need to send, I guess ...

Comment: @da_b0uncer Just send them.  The TCP stack (specifically the Nagle algorithm) will coalesce small packets if they're sent close enough together.  It's far better to let the network stack worry about this.